# POSIXTime as payload

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, pab

I have a parameterized contract that includes a POSIXTime as a field called startTime served via PAB.

What is the appropriate stringified HTTP payload to indicate a date with time such as the 25th of September 2021 at noon (no timezone?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had [troubles](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/3979) making `POSIXTime` a part of JSON payload, you can just unwrap the `Integer` inside and use it instead.

Anyway, JSON serialization is implemented [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/a3697f0ca6c51e8415a1433aa17159ab3986a4f5/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Time.hs#L66), you can check that instance for details.

If you need to convert `POSIXTime` to standard time format, something like this [function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#v:posixSecondsToUTCTime) would be useful.